# Create Magento Backend Field ReadOnly

Tags: magento, field, backend

I would like to create a read-only field in the backend at the client's Magento.
create fields to know (through a module) is as follows:

```
 $installer->addAttribute("customer", "attrcode",  array(
     "type"     => "varchar",
     "backend"  => "",
     "label"    => "label",
     "input"    => "text",
     "source"   => "",
     "visible"  => true,
     "required" => false,
     "default" => "",
     "frontend" => "",
     "unique"     => false,

    ));
```

this way it creates the field, but he's not just reading ...

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution is to use javascript to disable the button on page load

Create a js file and upload it to your admin skin/js directory (disable_button.js)

add

```
document.observe('dom:loaded', function(){
     $("target_input_id").disabled=true;
});
```

Then add or update you local.xml to include the js files

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <adminhtml_customer_edit>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><script>js/disable_button.js</script></action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_customer_edit>
</layout>
```

Comment: Sorry did not quite understand WHAT YOU meant.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think what you are trying to is possible using `addAttribute()`, `_prepareValues($attr)` method only allow specific values that are store in `$data`.

Take a look @ app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Setup.php

```
public function addAttribute($entityTypeId, $code, array $attr)
{
    $entityTypeId = $this->getEntityTypeId($entityTypeId);
    $data = array_merge(
        array(
            'entity_type_id' => $entityTypeId,
            'attribute_code' => $code
        ),
        $this->_prepareValues($attr);
     );
    .....
    if ($attributeId) {
        $this->updateAttribute($entityTypeId, $attributeId, $data, null, $sortOrder);
    } else {
        $this->_insertAttribute($data);
    }
    .......
 }


protected function _prepareValues($attr)
{
    $data = array(
        'backend_model'   => $this->_getValue($attr, 'backend'),
        'backend_type'    => $this->_getValue($attr, 'type', 'varchar'),
        'backend_table'   => $this->_getValue($attr, 'table'),
        'frontend_model'  => $this->_getValue($attr, 'frontend'),
        'frontend_input'  => $this->_getValue($attr, 'input', 'text'),
        'frontend_label'  => $this->_getValue($attr, 'label'),
        'frontend_class'  => $this->_getValue($attr, 'frontend_class'),
        'source_model'    => $this->_getValue($attr, 'source'),
        'is_required'     => $this->_getValue($attr, 'required', 1),
        'is_user_defined' => $this->_getValue($attr, 'user_defined', 0),
        'default_value'   => $this->_getValue($attr, 'default'),
        'is_unique'       => $this->_getValue($attr, 'unique', 0),
        'note'            => $this->_getValue($attr, 'note'),
        'is_global'       => $this->_getValue($attr, 'global',
                                 Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL
                             ),
    );

    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have developed exactly such extension that work for products, categories and CMS pages. You just have to define some rules and choose which attributes you want to show as read-only.

[image: Magento Products Admin Read-Only]

Extension URL: https://www.bubbleshop.net/magento-admin-readonly.html